# Add Swagger base path field in Nest.js project

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am trying to use nestjs/swagger to create a swagger file from my back-end and I am facing a problem related to the base path. What I want to achieve is to show version as base path instead of showing it in all the methods available, which is ugly and confusing.

My API, right now, has the following structure (this is a set of what is present in `app.module.ts`):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/api',
    module: ApiModule,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/v1',
        module: V1Module,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/orders',
            module: OrdersModule
          },
          {
            path: '/users',
            module: UsersModule
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This way, once I generate and check the swagger, I see all my methods following the `/api/v1` prefix. This could be an example:

**orders**

```
GET   /api/v1/orders
POST  /api/v1/orders
GET   /api/v1/orders/{order_id}
...
```

**users**

```
GET   /api/v1/users
POST  /api/v1/users
GET   /api/v1/users/{user_id}
...
```

What I want is to get rid of `/api/v1` appearing in any method. I know that SWAGGER has fields for `host` and `basePath`, but do not find any way to populate it in Nest.js. Researching, I have found that there were `.setBasePath()` and `.addServer()` methods, but they do not work for me (I am pretty sure they are deprecated).

Thank very much for your help.

Comment: But they are your endpoints though, aren't they?

Comment: Yeah but I do not want it to work that way. I want Nest.js to serve over /api/v1/

Comment: then I'd suggest not using `nestjs-router` at all

Comment: And then how can I route?

Comment: You don't need nestjs-router to route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want nestjs to add api/v1 to every endpoint then use `setGlobalPrefix('api/v1')` to do that.

https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix#global-prefix

Comment: I deleted my previous answers to update. This is really the way to go but I feel like it is poorly explained and confusing. What you have to do if you want to use `api/v1` as a global prefix is starting the app with `setGlobalPrefix('api/v1')`, delete the routes `api` and `v1` and set the children as main routes and add the configuration values `ingnoreGlobalPrefix` and `addServer('api/v1')`. I recommend you to update your answer to explain it.

Comment: You can use the versioning for the v1 part: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me `addServer(url)`